# How to Iterate through an array and find more than one elements

Tags: python, arrays, csv, jupyter-notebook

The Problem -
If I input more than one player's names. Only the first name comes up and the program then stops.
What can I do to print all names and the W/R Percentage presented by User's Input.

The code -

```
def print_player_data():
nba_data = pd.read_csv("csv_data.csv", sep=",")
dataList = []


player_names = input("Enter a list of player names: ")
player_names = player_names.split(",")
print(player_names)

for player in player_names:
    for index, row in nba_data.iterrows():
        if row["PLAYER_NAME"] == player:
            dataList.append(row["W/R_percentage"])
           
print(dataList)

            
    

print_player_data()
```

The Data -

PLAYER_NAME,TEAM_ABBREVIATION,Player Impact Rating,GP,Wins,Losses,W/R_percentage

Alex Len,ATL,0.1,77,28,49,36.36

Alex Poythress,ATL,0.069,21,7,14,33.33

Daniel Hamilton,ATL,0.07,19,7,12,36.84

DeAndre Bembry,ATL,0.081,82,29,53,35.37

Comment: Just tried your code, works exactly as expected. If I input multiple names, I get all names and all W/R_percentages for each player.
`Enter a list of player names: Alex Len,DeAndre Bembry    ['Alex Len', 'DeAndre Bembry']   [36.36, 35.37]`

 I can only imagine that something with your input goes wrong? Make sure you don't add a space after the commas

Comment: thanks @kappablanca, it really messed with my head. The problem was infact the space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like when inputting the names, you add spaces after the comma.
Add this line before iterating through your list to remove leading whitespaces:

```
player_names = [name.lstrip() for name in player_names]
```